# Changing angular routerLink depending on an observable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Using HTML in Angular, I seek an `<a>` tag that changes its routerlink depending on if a user is logged in or not. Is it possible to write the code in a single  tag

```
 <a *ngIf="!(accountService.currentUser$ | async)" class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">XXXX</a>
 <a *ngIf="accountService.currentUser$ | async" class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/members" routerLinkActive="active">XXXX</a>
```

Using ternary operator inside ngIf does not seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary for that:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="((accountService.currentUser$ | async) ? '/' : /members)" routerLinkActive="active">XXXX</a>
```